# In Rails, is restful_authentication a gem comparable to AuthLogic and OmniAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, restful-authentication

Two books (Learning Rails and Foundation Rails) both use restful_authentication gem / plugin to do user registration / activation.  Is it a gem comparable to AuthLogic and OmniAuth?

Is it still a good useable plugin for doing so and work well with Rails 3?  I thought GEM is the preferred method, and restful_authentication moved to github and it can be installed only as a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

- restful_auth is a rails plugin. It pollutes your code because it generates code.
- authlogic is newer than restful_auth. It's a gem instead of rails plugin so your code is much cleaner than using restful_auth
- omniauth is a newer gem than authlogic but it uses external provider e.g OpenID, OAuth, etc, instead of your database.

The latest authlogic works well with Rails 3 with a few hitch.